# Office 2010 UserForm handling Pages in MultiPage Control

Tags: vba, ms-office

I am currently working on migrating from Office 2002 SP3 to Office 2010.

In an Excel Workbook with heavy use of VBA i am running into the following Problem:

The following function is working like a charme in 2002, but crashes when opened with 2010.

```
Private Function fktSeeall()
   Dim pPage As Page, cCont As Control, mpMultiPage As Control

   If Seeall Then
       cbButton2.Caption = "Leere ausblenden"
   Else
       cbButton2.Caption = "Alle anzeigen"
   End If
   For Each mpMultiPage In Me.Controls
       If TypeName(mpMultiPage) = "MultiPage" Then
           For Each pPage In mpMultiPage.Pages
               pPage.Visible = Seeall
               For Each cCont In pPage.Controls
                   If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" And cCont.Text <> "" Then
                       pPage.Visible = True
                       mpMultiPage.Value = Right(pPage.Name, 1) - 1
                   End If
               Next cCont
           Next pPage
       End If
   Next
End Function
```

The boolean `Seeall` is set outside the function.
All pages are containing one textbox. If seeall is set to false, every Page exept the ones with filled Textboxes are hidden. If set to true, all Pages are shown again.

Office 2010 fails at the line
`For Each pPage In mpMultiPage.Pages` with error message code 13 "Type Dismatch"

It also fails if i use

```
For Each pPage In MultiPage1.Pages
    pPage.Visible = Seeall
    For Each cCont In pPage.Controls
        If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" And cCont.Text <> "" Then
            pPage.Visible = True
            MultiPage1.Value = Right(pPage.Name, 1) - 1
        End If
    Next cCont
Next pPage
```

I dont get the point, why the new office version fails at this stage of my code.

This is a screenshot of the UserForm:
[image]

Comment: I can't quite figure out why yet but tell me if it works if you change `Dim pPage As Page` to `Dim pPage As Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured it out!

From Excel 2007 onwards the Object Model has an object called Page which isn't the same as the Forms Page.

Reference the Form Page property explicitly using `Dim pPage As msforms.Page` instead of `Dim pPage As Page`